# Error in Json parsing in unnamed array

Tags: json

> 12-02 11:18:07.479: E/Buffer Error(21355): Error converting result
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 12-02
>   11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355): java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occured while executing doInBackground() 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278) 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 12-02
>   11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 12-02
>   11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116) 12-02
>   11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94) 12-02
>   11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):    at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:87) 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:103) 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity$GetDataAsyncTask.getData(MainActivity.java:92)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity$GetDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity$GetDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264) 12-02 11:18:07.919:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   12-02 11:18:07.919: E/AndroidRuntime(21355):  ... 5 more 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355): Activity
>   com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41747ba0 that
>   was originally added here 12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):
>   android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity
>   has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41747ba0 that
>   was originally added here 12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:403) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278) 12-02 11:18:17.339:
>   E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity$GetDataAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:72)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511) 12-02 11:18:17.339:
>   E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   com.example.icsnepal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-02 11:18:17.339:
>   E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-02 11:18:17.339:
>   E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   12-02 11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 12-02
>   11:18:17.339: E/WindowManager(21355):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please go through the FAQ of this site,MAke sure your question is properly formatted and understandable for others

Comment: lovely error stack trace , any points for giving us the key to your code